# SSIS Script Task: How to update table from List<T>

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

What is the best way to update a table from a List inside an SSIS Script Task?

We have a shared class library. I have used the dll in the script task to do most of the necessary work. The dll method then returns a List which contains data related to the processes that it ran. It is my job to write this list to a table.

I'm thinking I will loop through each item in the List and and run the update SQL statement.

For brevity, I did not paste the SQL statement, but it is actually an Upsert using MERGE.

Actually, I wish there were a way to output the List to the input of an Execute SQL Task, but I'm unsure if that is possible.

Here is what I have so far. As you can see it is unfinished.

```
  private void UpdateEtlData(List<ProcessStatitics> statistics)
    {
        var connection = GetOhioConnectionString();

        // will loop thru each item in statistics and run the 
        // following sequence. This code is unfinished, but
        // I will use properties inside each statistic to form the 
        // query
        foreach(statistic in statistics)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = ""
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the list come from?

Comment: Need more detail

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: The list comes from a custom dll. The dll is a class library and it is doing most of the work then writing back some details in the process in the form of a List. It is my job to write this list to a table.

Comment: @paparazzo: I have added some detail.

Comment: Have you managed to pass the DLL supplied list into the SSIS script task? I think that is going to be your biggest challenge. SSIS might not be the best tool for this. Do you need to pass parameters into the custom dll?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Yes. I have the list inside the script task and can access all its elements. Now I just need to output to a table. The dll does not require parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do here is to create your SQLCommand outside of the loop, and set it up with parameters to write your data. This blog post covers it well: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Steps are:

```
// 1. declare command object with parameter
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "Insert into CityList (CityName) values (@City)", conn);
// 2. define parameters used in command object
    SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@City";
// 3. add new parameter to command object
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

// When you want to assign the value
    param.Value = inputCity;
```

Then in your loop you can assign your value from the list to param.Value, and call command.ExecuteNonQuery